# Select specific indexes of 3D Pytorch Tensor using a 1D long tensor that represents indexes

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

So I have a tensor that is M x B x C, where M is the number of models, B is the batch and C is the classes and each cell is the probability of a class for a given model and batch. Then I have a tensor of the correct answers which is just a 1D of size B we'll call "t". How do I use the 1D of size B to just return a M x B x 1, where the returned tensor is just the value at the correct class? Say the M x B x C tensor is called "blah" I've tried

```
blah[:, :, C]

for i in range(M):
    blah[i, :, C]

blah[:, C, :]
```

The top 2 just return the values of indexes t in the 3rd dimension of every slice. The last one returns the values at t indexes in the 2nd dimension. How do I do this?

Comment: `blah[:,range(B),t]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the desired result by [combining advanced and basic indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing)

```py
import torch

# shape [2, 3, 4]
blah = torch.tensor([
    [[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
     [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
     [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],
    [[12, 13, 14, 15],
     [16, 17, 18, 19],
     [20, 21, 22, 23]]])

# shape [3]
t = torch.tensor([2, 1, 0])
b = torch.arange(blah.shape[1]).type_as(t)

# shape [2, 3, 1]
result = blah[:, b, t].unsqueeze(-1)
```

which results in

```py
>>> result
tensor([[[ 2],
         [ 5],
         [ 8]],
        [[14],
         [17],
         [20]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

Suppose `a` is your `M x B x C` shaped tensor. I am taking some representative values below,

```py
>>> M = 3
>>> B = 5
>>> C = 4
>>> a = torch.rand(M, B, C)
>>> a
tensor([[[0.6222, 0.6703, 0.0057, 0.3210],
         [0.6251, 0.3286, 0.8451, 0.5978],
         [0.0808, 0.8408, 0.3795, 0.4872],
         [0.8589, 0.8891, 0.8033, 0.8906],
         [0.5620, 0.5275, 0.4272, 0.2286]],

        [[0.2419, 0.0179, 0.2052, 0.6859],
         [0.1868, 0.7766, 0.3648, 0.9697],
         [0.6750, 0.4715, 0.9377, 0.3220],
         [0.0537, 0.1719, 0.0013, 0.0537],
         [0.2681, 0.7514, 0.6523, 0.7703]],

        [[0.5285, 0.5360, 0.7949, 0.6210],
         [0.3066, 0.1138, 0.6412, 0.4724],
         [0.3599, 0.9624, 0.0266, 0.1455],
         [0.7474, 0.2999, 0.7476, 0.2889],
         [0.1779, 0.3515, 0.8900, 0.2301]]])
```

Let's say the 1D class tensor is `t`, which gives the true class of each example in the batch. So it is a 1D tensor of shape `(B, )` having class labels in the range `{0, 1, 2, ..., C-1}`.

```
>>> t = torch.randint(C, size = (B, ))
>>> t
tensor([3, 2, 1, 1, 0])
```

So basically you want to select the indices corresponding to `t` from the innermost dimension of `a`. This can be achieved using [fancy indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) and [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) combined as follows:

```
>>> i = torch.arange(M).reshape(M, 1, 1)
>>> j = torch.arange(B).reshape(1, B, 1)
>>> k = t.reshape(1, B, 1)
```

Note that once you index anything by `(i, j, k)`, they are going to [expand](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.expand) and take the shape `(M, B, 1)` which is the desired output shape.
Now just indexing `a` by `i`, `j` and `k` gives:

```
>>> a[i, j, k]
tensor([[[0.3210],
         [0.8451],
         [0.8408],
         [0.8891],
         [0.5620]],

        [[0.6859],
         [0.3648],
         [0.4715],
         [0.1719],
         [0.2681]],

        [[0.6210],
         [0.6412],
         [0.9624],
         [0.2999],
         [0.1779]]])
```

So essentially, if you generate the index arrays conveying your access pattern beforehand, you can directly use them to extract some slice of the tensor.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to pass:

- your index as the third slice
- `range(B)` as the second slice
  (i.e. which element in the 2nd dim each 3rd dim index corresponds to)

```py
blah[:,range(B),t]
```